# Query tags/context labels of senses using JWKTL

Tags: parsing, wiktionary

I am working on a project where I need to deal with Wiktionary. For some entries, there are context labels/tags before its sense I want to query for, e.g. idiomatic, transitive like [HERE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/look_up). I am now trying to use [JWKTL](https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-jwktl), to do the job. But it seems no api call supports the query.

Can anyone let me know how to get that information by JWKTL, or, is there any other tool can parse the Wiktionary dump .xml file while being able to access that labels/tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Dr. Christian. Meyer, there is currently no API on this.

I ended up with pattern matching in the original wiktionary .xml dump.